# create dataframe from lists of different size

Tags: python, dataframe

Could you help me to find a way to create a dataframe from a list  Here is an example:

```
['E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88']
['E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88']
['E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88']
['E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164', 'E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18']
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
['E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']
['E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']
['E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88', 'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']
['E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164','E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18']
```

before creating the dataframe. Thanks for your help

Comment: None of them are valid dictionaries.

Comment: Don't you mean lists?

Comment: If you have items inside curly brackets without the dictionary `key, value` pairs, it's called a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the max lenth of the lists what will be the lenth the lists would have be in the result. Fill up every list with `NaN`s to the required lenth.

```
data = [ ['E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88'],
['E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88'],
['E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88'],
['E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164', 'E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18']]


lenth = len(max(data, key=len))  # the lenth the lists have to be

for arr in data:
    arr += ['NaN'] * (lenth - len(arr))  # adding required 'NaN's
```

```
>>> print(data)
[
    ['E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    ['E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    ['E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    ['E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164', 'E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = {'E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88'}
b = {'E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88'}
c = {'E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88'}
d = {'E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164', 'E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18'}


df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d])
```

If you have `dictionary` format, you can try follows:

```
dict_ = dict({'key1' : ['E139', 'E216', 'E248', 'E111', 'E91', 'E245', 'E88'],
              'key2' : ['E102', 'E139', 'E216', 'E238', 'E186', 'E111', 'E91', 'E88'],
              'key3' : ['E256', 'E46', 'E232', 'E139', 'E37', 'E216', 'E235', 'E73', 'E91', 'E88'],
              'key4' : ['E230', 'E31', 'E198', 'E237', 'E233', 'E10', 'E120', 'E46', 'E82', 'E25', 'E164', 'E253', 'E104', 'E54', 'E18']
              })
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_.values()))
```